# changing repeats value of UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger

Tags: swift, repeat, localnotification

i have a local notification that i am repeating every 60s:

```
var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true);
```

i want to change the `repeats` value of the `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` from `true` to `false` if a certain condition is met i.e.:

```
if (condition) {
    trigger!.repeats = true;
}
```

however this doesn't seem to work as i dont think i can change the `repeats` value after creating the object.

is there any way to do what i'm trying to do?

Comment: If condition is met, you can create another one with `true` or `false`. Also you should cancel an older notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the local notification as

```
UIApplication.shared.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
```

And if you want to `true` again then again assign

```
trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: true)
```

May be this Work

Comment: It's an iOS 10! You can cancel all of the local notifications from `UNUserNotificationCenter`

Comment: UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()